# Apt no longer working at all due to bad mirrors

Tags: apt, 20.04, mirrors

I am trying to install/update literally anything on my machine but I can't because it always uses a bad mirror and I can't find any way to change it.

```
Temporary failure resolving 'ru.archive.ubuntu.com'
```

I get this every time, despite not being in Russia. I installed my OS a few years ago when I was living there, now I can't figure out how to change the mirror.

I wanted to try `apt-mirror-updater` but I can't because I don't have pip installed and can't install it because of the same error. All solutions that I have found involve installing some Python thing, which I obviously can't do. How can I fix this?

Comment: have you tried to update your system via synaptic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to replace the corresponding line from /etc/apt/sources.list by another mirror that works.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then find and replace all *ru.archive.ubuntu.com* by (for example) *be.archive.ubuntu.com*.

Here's a list of mirrors: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

Comment: I had done this previously with no luck, still going to `ru.archive.ubuntu.com`. However, I realized that I had forgot to run `apt update` to update that. Working now. Thanks.